# PHP: html dropdown with 2 values, one hidden

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm making a HTML form with a dropdown list that pulls in values from an SQL (Server) statement. There are two values, PCName and IPAddress. I want to display the returned values for PCName in a list and when the user selects an entry and hits submit, I want to use the associated IP address as the result.
The first if-statement checks if there are valid results for another, earlier test and if so creates the dropdown list.

```
      <?php
        if ($rowok) {
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"connType\" value=\"PCs\"> PCs ";
            echo "<select name=\"PCs\" style = \"font-family : Courier New\">";
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
                //sName = $row[0]; sIP = $row[1];
                echo "<option value='" . $row[0] . "'>" . $row[0] . "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
         } 
      ?>
```

I have assigned the two columns returned by the query two values but am not sure how to exploit them.

I want to reference the content of selected item in the list (PC name) but use the hidden value (IP address)
This will give me the value of the PC name:

```
$select1 = $_POST['PCs'];
```

but how can I retrieve the value of sIP/row[1] for the user-selected item?
I *could* maybe send another SQL query using the returned value of PC name to get its IP, but I really don't like that idea.

Comment: But based on your html you will need to change to `$select1 = $_POST['PCs'];` as that is the name you gave to your `<select>` tag

Comment: sorry, pasted the wrong line. corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a JSON like string as an `option` value, and then use `json_decode()` to convert it to array once posted:

```
<form name="conn" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <select name="PCs">
        <option value='{"name":"0","sip":"1"}'>01</option>
        <option value='{"name":"2","sip":"3"}'>23</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$pc = json_decode($_POST['PCs'], true);
print_r($pc);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => 0
    [sip] => 1
)
```

Now you can access both values via `$pc['name']` and/or `$pc['sip']` after POST;

Comment: NICE, I had never thought of using JSON, of course I had never needed to pass more than one value, but whatever, nice trick

Comment: @RiggsFolly, true, but better than playing with JS onchange events and hidden fields.

Comment: The list is displaying the PC name but the value of $pc[name] and $pc[sip] are null
I might have messed up the escaping but the HTML seems to display fine.
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) { $sName = $row[0]; $sIP = $row[1].",".$row[2]; echo "<option value='{\"name\":".$sName."\",\"sip\":".$sIP."}'>".$sName."</option>"; }
$PCs = json_decode($_POST['PCs'], true);
echo $PCs['sip'];

Comment: got it eventually, just needed to escape-quote the IP addresses as well:
echo "<option value='{\"name\":\"".$sName."\",\"sip\":\"".$sIP."\"}'>".$sName."</option>";

Answer (score 2):

So if i'm reading this right you want both the PC Name and PC IP.

Then this should do it for you, using jQuery.

```
  <?php
    if ($rowok) {
        echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"connType\" value=\"PCs\"> PCs ";
        echo "<select name=\"PCs\" onchange=\"setIp()\" style = \"font-family : Courier New\">";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
            //sName = $row[0]; sIP = $row[1];
            echo "<option value='" . $row[0] . "'>" . $row[0] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
     } 

echo('<div id="hiddenIp"></div>');
```

Then add this to your page footer

```
<script>
function setIp() {
  $('#hiddenIp').html('<input id="pcIp" type="hidden" name="pcIp" value="'+$('#PCs :selected').text()+'">')
}
</script>
```

Then when you submit the form using POST you can get the values using `$_POST["PCs"]` and `$_POST["pcIp"]`

Comment: I'm getting "Undefined index: pcIp" when I try to retrieve $_POST["pcIp"]

Comment: @pickarooney sorry, forgot to set the name in the script correctly, just updated it for you now.